# How to debug custom component in Oracle Digital Assistant?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I'm writing a component for Oracle Chatbot, but I can't and don't know to debug my code.

My component imports with success to Oracle Digital Assistant (ODA), but I have a lot of work to test.

My component:

```
"use strict"
module.exports = {

    metadata: () => ({
        "name": "DocumentNumber",
        "properties": {
            "numberDocument": { "type": "string", "required": true }
        },
        "supportedActions": [
            "allow",
            "block"
        ]
    }),

    invoke: (conversation, done) => {
        // Parse a number out of the incoming message
        const text = conversation.text();

        var document = "";
        if (text) {
            const textSize = text.length;
            if (textSize < 10) {
                conversation.invalidUserInput("xxxxxx");

                done();
                return;
            } else {
                document = text;
            }
        } else {
            var errText = "xxxx";
            conversation.logger().error(errText);
            done(new Error(errText));
            return;
        }

        conversation.logger().info('DocumentNumber: using numberDocumento=' + document);


        var express = require('express');


        var linkReturn = "";
        axios.put('http://xxxxx', {
            numeroDocumento: document,
            filial: 0001
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            linkReturn = response;
            console.log(response);

          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            linkReturn = "";
            console.log(error);
          });

        // Set action based on age check
        //conversation.invalidUserInput(linkReturn);

        if (linkReturn !== ""){
            conversation.invalidUserInput(linkReturn);
            conversation.transition('allow');
        } else {
            conversation.invalidUserInput(response.data);
            conversation.transition('block');
        }

        done();
    }
};
```

I would like to know how to debug my component setting a value for properties numberDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at this documentation of how to create a custom component?

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/digital-assistant/tutorial-cc-dev/index.html#DeployYourCustomComponentServicetotheSkill

There is a chapter on how to import it into ODA and how to test it.

If you to your components in the Oracle Cloud you in the top right you can select:
[image]

This will show the things you put in your conversation.logger().info() hence you have to replace your `console.log()` with `conversation.logger().info("Stuff to log.")`